# AngularFire2: you are using the development build of the firebase SDK

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angular6, angularfire2, angularfire5

So i'm using the official documentation to setup and install angularfire2. 
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md

This works fine, my data is coming in but when building for production i get this error:

> It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS
>   SDK. When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to
>   only import the individual SDK components you intend to use.
>
> For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
>   (replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database,
>   etc):

I tried every suggestion out there but nothing is working.

Any Ideas?
thx,

**Root module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { RootComponent } from './rootComponent.component';
import { ROOT_ROUTES } from './root.routes';
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [RootComponent],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROOT_ROUTES)
  ],
  providers: [Title],
  bootstrap: [RootComponent]
})
export class RootModule {}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Seal } from '../seals.types';
import { StudioService } from '../../../service/studio.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'seals-component',
    templateUrl: './seals.component.html'
})
export class SealsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private db:AngularFirestore, private studioService: StudioService) {
        this.getData();
    }

    items: Observable<any[]>;
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Seal[]>();;
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['description', 'language', 'seal', 'type'];
    pID:string = 'flsjezlijlsfj';

    ngOnInit() {}

    getData() {
        this.items = this.db.collection(`sealsDB/TNDorQMQOzoqY6P6Ej0i/seal/${this.pID}/seal/`).valueChanges();
        this.items.subscribe(seals => {
            this.dataSource.data = seals
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same warning and it took me a while to figure it out that I was using the `User` interface from `firebase/auth`, along with `Timestamp.fromDate()` in other file.

So I added:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { User } from 'firebase/auth';
```

and just

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

where I used

```
firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate()
```

This got rid of the warning.